# Реализация метода в наследниках или просто несколько функций?

Tags: python, архитектура, интерфейс, проектирование

Предположим, есть какая-то функциональность, для которой можно создать несколько реализаций. Для примера пусть будет анализ текста. И есть какой-то код, которому эта функциональность нужна, т.е. что-то типа:

```
def use_case():
    # preprocessing
    result = analyze_text(some_text)
    # post processing
```

Реализовать этот анализ текста можно по-разному, и я хочу понять, какой подход лучше, и почему:

**Вариант 1**. Интерфейс и классы с фактической реализацией. Т.е. что-то типа:

```
class TextAnalyzer:
    def analyze(self, text):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Analyzer1(TextAnalyzer):
    def analyze(self, text):
        # implementation 1
        ...

class Analyzer2(TextAnalyzer):
    def analyze(self, text):
        # implementation 2
        ...
```

и тогда вызывающий код будет создавать (или откуда-то получать) объект `analyzer = Analyzer1()` и вызывать `analyzer.analyze(some_text)`

**Вариант 2**. Просто несколько функций с разными реализациями. Т.е. что-то типа:

```
def analyze1():
    # implementation 1
    ...

def analyze2():
    # implementation 2
    ...
```

вызывающий код опять-таки может сам просто в нужном месте вызывать `analyze1()`, или же получать откуда-то объект функции `analyze_function = analyze1` и потом уже его вызывать.

Какой вариант более предпочтителен и более питоновский и почему?

P.S.

Я долгое время писал на `java`, поэтому мне ближе подход с созданием интерфейса и реализацией в подклассах, но сейчас, думая о преимуществах такого подхода, я не могу найти каких-то серьёзных пунктов **За** и **Против** кроме, быть может, проверки типов, но я не уверен, возможно для функций это тоже осуществимо

Comment: Не знаю как в питоне, но, например, в случае интерфейсов и реализаций, можно логику сконфигурировать через какой нить DI типа спринга. Иметь же просто несколько функций и вызывать конкретную когда надо - по сути такое не сконфигурировать, это выглядит как строго зашитая логика. То есть если вам надо строго зашитое - функции и их вызовы выглядят как выбор, если таки какая то гибкость подразумевается - то интерфейсы для гибкости и созданы.

Comment: @tym32167 вот да, для java я тоже такие плюсы вижу. Но в питоне функции ведь тоже объекты, поэтому вполне возможно, что какой-нибудь питоновский DI (сам я никогда не пользовался) и их сможет отлично внедрить. Мне интересно как делают в таких случаях на питоне, возможно есть какое-то общепринятое питоновское правило для таких случаев

Comment: Вопрос неподходящий для этой ветки stackoverflow - функциональное программирование против ООП.

Comment: Питоновские  функции, если я верно понял (что вообще не факт) - это аналог функциональных интерфейсов. Я бы такое был ок использовать в утилитарных классах, типа как они используются в стримах, но не стал бы на них строить бизнес логику. Писать конкретный алгоритм в функциональном стиле - почему бы и нет, но строить какие то бизнес транзакции на этом - тут вопрос вопросов.

Comment: я бы класс сделал, и туда методов напихал. почему? ну просто потом у тебя будет расти методы анализатора и проще потом ориентироваться.

Comment: Тут уже упомянули Spring. Чтож, в python, в django, есть метапрограммирование, когда классы создаются на лету.

Comment: Интерфейсы рулят, конечно же. В том же `Scikit-learn` это активно используется. Если у вас есть универсальный интерфейс, вы можете строить цепочки вызовов и вообще много чего, легко подменяя если нужно одни классы другими. Просто поменял где-то инициализацию объекта - а дальше весь код работает так же, методы то у всех у них универсальные и взаимозаменяемые. А если нужно менять названия используемых функций, то это нужно бегать по всему коду, искать где они там вызываются и менять их. Как-то не очень выглядит.

Comment: @CrazyElf не особо понял про цепочки вызовов, к примеру если метод из вопроса будет возвращать что-то типа `хороший текст/плохой`, то какие тут цепочки. Если же вопрос в изменении инициализации чтобы не бегать по всему коду, то, как упомянули выше, функция в питоне это по сути функциональный объект, который тоже вполне можно 1 раз где-то сохранить в переменную и потом везде передавать/внедрять точно так же как и в случае с объектами классов. Собственно вопрос именно из-за этой фишки с `функция - это объект` и возник.

Comment: Но в общем суть я уловил, с интерфейсами код более понятный и читаемый будет, т.к., скорее всего, будут яснее намерения программиста предоставить удобный и сразу заметный механизм замены реализации.